# JQuery Mobile Widget not Formatting on Dynamic Content on Re-Visits

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

I have a single page jQuery Mobile app with four "data-role='pages'" in place; so, essentially, it's one HTML doc with four "pages."

Each "page" also has a navigation footer that I am populating dynamically through javascript. I defined a variable called "theFooter," and assigned all my empty footer divs (with classes of "footer") like so:

```
$('.footer').html(theFooter);
```

Now, in order to get this to work properly, I have to populate those footers PRIOR to the page being created, otherwise jQuery Mobile won't apply it framework to make the footer bar look like a mobile app nav bar.
So I achieve that through this:

```
$( "div[data-role='page']").live('pagebeforecreate', function (evt) {
    console.log("BEFORE CREATE run."); //writes to my fireBug console to alert me that     the 'page' has been run
    $('.footer').html(theFooter);
});
```

It works like a dream, the first time around. Let's suppose the pages are "about," "contact," "mission," and "calendar"…

You click "about"… perfect.

You click "contact".. perfect.

You can do this for each of the "pages," and each time the "pagebeforecreate" is fired and the footer looks GREAT.

HOWEVER, if now you click on, say, "about" again (or any of the ones that you've already visited), the page transitions and the content is in place, but there is NO JQUERY MOBILE FORMATTING.  And it is not firing the 'pagebeforecreate' function again, which makes sense, because it has already been created the first time.

I've tried working with 'pageinit' and 'pagebeforeshow' firings, but have gotten nowhere.

I have tried .trigger() and .page() methods… and got nowhere.

Can someone explain exactly how to make that JQuery Mobile formatting stick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call `.trigger('create')` on the parent element of the widget you can enhance it's markup at any point in time:

```
$( "div[data-role='page']").live('pagebeforecreate', function (evt) {
    console.log("BEFORE CREATE run."); //writes to my fireBug console to alert me that     the 'page' has been run
    $('.footer').html(theFooter).trigger('create');
});
```

Comment: Jasper,Thanks... that solved one problem I was having, but created another one with some formatting I was adding. I probably could figure it out if I knew what I did. What, exactly, does the trigger('create') function do to my code?

Comment: `trigger('create')` initializes any widgets found: `$('[data-role="listview"]').trigger('create')` will initialize all found `listview` widgets. When a widget gets initialized the structure of the HTML will be altered and a lot of attribute work is done (classes are added, aria attributes are added, data-attributes are added, etc). So if you plan on altering the widget after it's been initialized, don't expect it to be the same code that existed before initialization. Inspect the initialized widgets in your developer tools to see the changes made to the markup.

Comment: Ah, OK. Yeah, so what I was doing was appending on some custom CSS after initialization. So when it gets re-initialize, it probably wipes out all my custom CSS and just goes back to the "out of the box" widget css, is that right? So perhaps I will make those customizations in a function and all that after the trigger. I'll try that this weekend or Monday and let you know how it makes out. Can I do a callback function on a trigger()?

Comment: Yup, seems to work. I assign the data when 'pagebeforecreate' is fired, and then put the .trigger('create') AND the call to format the CSS when 'pageinit' is fired. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,user-scalable=no,initial-scale=1.0"/>
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="jquery.mobile-1.0.1.css" /> 
<title> Hello World </title>

<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {

$('#omtList').html('<ul data-role="listview" data-split-icon="delete" data-split-theme="d"> <li><a href="index.html"><h3>Broken Bells</h3><p>Broken Bells</p></a><a href="lists-split-purchase.html" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="slideup">Purchase album </a></ul>').trigger('create');
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
omt
<div>
    <div id="omtList">  


    </div><!--/content-primary -->  
</body>
</html>
```